# Solving orders task

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have two orders $A=\{1,2,5,6,8\}$ and $B=\{3,4,5,8,9\}$.

I have to find $A\bigcup B$,  $A\bigcap B$,  $A$/$B$ and  $B$/$A$. I don't know how to solve this. First I must admit that I don't know what $\bigcup $ and $\bigcap$ operations are. I suppose that "/" means divide.

Can you please give me short logic how to start solving this. Brief explanations please.

Comment: Should be union and intersection of sets, I feel....

Comment: I also feel that the "/" should be "$\setminus$", the set-difference operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\cup B$ is the union of the two sets; also known as the disjunction, and contains all elements which are in either $A$ **or** $B$ (inclusively).

$A\cap B$ is the intersection of the two sets; also known as the conjunction, or joint, and contains all elements which are in both $A$ **and** $B$.

$A\setminus B$ is the set difference, and contains all elements that are in $A$ except for those that are also in $B$.   Sometimes you will see it written as $A-B$ or $A\smallsetminus B$.   (Never as $A / B$.)

$B\setminus A$ is also a set difference, this one contains all elements that are in $B$ except for those that are also in $A$.

To check you work: there should be no common element in any two of the last three, and the first is the disjunction of all of them.

$$A\cup B= (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B\setminus A)$$

Comment: This is very nice explanation, but how am I start to solve this? Can you please give little example

Comment: {0} union {1}= {0,1}.  A and B are not orders, they are sets.

Comment: Does my calculations correct: $A\cup B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9\}$,   $A\cap B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,6,8,8,9\}$,  $A\setminus B = \{1,2,6\}$, $B\setminus A = \{3,4,9\}$

Comment: @TeodorKolev $A\cup B, A\setminus B, B\setminus A$ are okay.  $A\cap B$ is not; sets do not contain duplicated members. $A\cap B$ contains the elements that are in $A$ and are in $B$ , that is the elements those sets have in common .

Comment: @GrahamKemp Then I don't see any difference between $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$

Comment: It is the difference betwixt "or" and "and". $A\cup B = \{x: x\in A\vee x\in B\}$, that is the set of elements that are in at least one from the two sets, whilst $A\cap B = \{x: x\in A\wedge x\in B\}$, that is the set of elements that are common to both (not in just one; *both*).

Comment: Thus $\{a,b\}\cup\{b,c\}=\{a,b,c\}$ while $\{a,b\}\cap\{b,c\}=\{b\}$.  @TeodorKolev

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks again